# what is [Reverted] during contract execution

Tags: transactions, contract-deployment, contract-invocation, revert-opcode

I have sent ETH to a contract address, and it "failed" the transaction saying it is: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

contract address and transaction failure here:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x84f659b078abc10c419c59f90e81263817b0b645fd05e56effe52389697aa990

can someone help and explain please?

Theo

Answer (score 2):

Revert is a new opcode from Byzantium. When an execution throws, before Byzantium, all gas was consumed and the contract remained in the previous state (it rolled back). Now, it doesn't consume all gas, because with this opcode the execution get's reverted and the remaining gas gets returned to the function caller.

Comment: Ok so it is preventing the execution to save the gas. But then why is it preventing the execution?

Comment: It is the equivalent of a throw, why your code throws, i don't know

Comment: I thought that.. But I can't find the error in the code.. ☠ ((((  it's getting frustrating